# How can I verify client certificates against a CRL in Golang?

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2

I'm using the `ClientCAs` and `ClientAuth` options in `tls.Config` to do cert-based client authentication in my Go HTTP application. Is it possible to also verify the client certs against a provided CRL? I see in the `x509` package there are some functions around CRLs, but I'm not sure how to configure the HTTP server to use them (ie. there doesn't seem to be any options in `tls.Config` that would cause a CRL to also be used).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to also verify the client certs against a provided CRL?

Yes, it is possible, by means of the functionality provided in the `crypto/x509` package (as you correctly stated in your question). However, higher-level interfaces such as `crypto/tls.Config` (consumed by `net/http`) do not offer that. A good chance to implement a check against a CRL probably is by inspecting `net/http.Request.TLS.PeerCertificates`.

A little bit of background: [`crypto/tls` is maintained by security expert Adam Langley](https://github.com/golang/go/commits/master?author=agl) who has an [opinion on revocation checking](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7615273) (original source is [his blog](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/04/19/revchecking.html)). Though I have no evidence, one might assume that this was a deliberate design decision.

Comment: Thanks @flowlo, I'll dig deeper into the PeerCertificates option you suggested. As for Adam's post on CRLs, I get what he's saying from a client-side perspective. When using certs for server-side auth though, CRLs are still vital.

Comment: Manually verifying the peer certificates looks to be a valid approach. Would just have to be done as middleware somewhere in the server call stack. For future reference, the code at https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/blob/master/revoke/revoke.go has some good examples of how to actually compare peer certificates against a CRL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VerifyPeerCertificate](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config.VerifyPeerCertificate) to validate connections against your CRL file. Simply iterate over your list of revoked certificates and check if the serial number of the revoked certs is equal to the peer certificiate's serial number.